# Create a defined number of Label in a for loop

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, dynamic, label

I want to create dynamically 10 Labels inside a for loop

```
string labelName;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    labeName = "Label" & i;
    // Creata & Instanciate the label here, How ?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How would you create a bunch of objects which *weren't* UI elements? Use a collection:

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    // Set properties here
    labels.Add(label);
}
```

You'll presumably want to add these labels to a form or page or whatever too...

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> labelName = new List<string>();    
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    labeName.Add(string.Concat("Label", i));
}
```